# Adding view from xib in front of other views

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to add a custom view from a xib in front of other views. However, for some reason it's never placed as the front view when theres a `UITableView` on screen. Here's my code:

```
noInternetView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("NoInternetView", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! NoInternetView
noInternetView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
noInternetView.delegate = self

self.view.addSubview(noInternetView)
self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: noInternetView, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: noInternetView, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
```

I place this at the bottom of my `viewDidLoad()` code. Why could this be?

Comment: Can you try it in viewdidappear and let me know if it works.I have done what you did but my view was in storyboard and have loaded custom views from xib without any kind of issue.So how can you tell if the view is going behind the other views "Debug View Hierarchy"??

Answer (score 0):

```
noInternetView.hidden = true
```

your view is hidden, do it visible

```
noInternetView.hidden = false
```

Comment: Sorry, you're correct but actually that was a mistake in my code here. Without that, it's still below other subviews. I've removed that from the code in my question to avoid confusion!

Comment: also try addChildViewController(noInternetView!)
view.addSubview((noInternetView?.view)!)

Comment: noInternetView isn't a view controller though, it's just a UIView subclass

Answer (score 0):

```
self.view.bringSubviewToFront(noInternetView)
```

Try this it may help you.

Comment: where you have add this line after addsubview or before that?

Answer (score 0):

First

Check is there a noInternetView have width and height constraints

Second

Add `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` after `self.view.addConstraint`

this help to adjust autolayout you added

Answer (score 0):

If you want your view to be on the top, add it to the window instead.